# Operate on multiple .xlsx files where data can be in a different column in each file

Tags: excel, vba

I created a macro to do operations in files like that:

**Column A:** Id numbers
**Column B:** English Source Text
**Column C:** Text for translation

My macro asks for a folder address then for every xlsx file in that folder, it opens that file and copies column B to C, hides Columns B and A and saves the file.

```
Sub preprocess()

    ' To use this macro you can use the shortcut Ctrl + n
    Dim wbOpen As Workbook
    Dim MyDir As Variant
    'Dim MyDir As String

    MyDir = InputBox("Paste here the folder where you excel files are located.")

    'MyDir = "C:\Users\E.DeAlmeidaLebre\Desktop\onDemand\Jira\MACROS\Test" 'This is the path to your files

    strExtension = Dir(MyDir & "\*.xlsx")

    While strExtension <> vbNullString
        Set wbOpen = Workbooks.Open(MyDir & "\" & strExtension)

        With wbOpen

            'Copy Column B to Column C
            Range("B1:B9999").Copy Range("C1:C9999")

            'Overwrite English for Translation on cell C1
            Range("C1").Value = "Translation"

            'Hide Columns
            Columns("A").Hidden = True
            Columns("B").Hidden = True

            .Close SaveChanges:=True

        End With

        strExtension = Dir

    Wend

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

I now have several xlsx files that the English Column is located in columns other than C.

For this example let's say I have five types of files.

1. English Column located on Column C
2. English Column located on Column D
3. English Column located on Column E
4. English Column located on Column D
5. English Column located on Column F

I want that my macro handles the same for every file type, for example if it is case 5, copies column F to G, hides Columns A, B, C, D and E and saves the file.

I wrote a macro below. There are no errors. It opens the files but doesn't run the operations.

Here is the new macro:

```
Sub multimacro()

    ' To use this macro you can use the shortcut Ctrl + n
    Dim wbOpen As Workbook
    Dim MyDir As Variant
    'Dim MyDir As String
    Dim c As Range
    MyDir = InputBox("Paste here the folder where you excel files are located.")

    'MyDir = "C:\Users\E.DeAlmeidaLebre\Desktop\onDemand\Jira\MACROS\Test" 'This is the path to your files

    strExtension = Dir(MyDir & "\*.xlsx")

    While strExtension <> vbNullString
        Set wbOpen = Workbooks.Open(MyDir & "\" & strExtension)

        With wbOpen

            For Each c In Range("A1:AK1")
                If c.Value = "English" Then
                    MsgBox "FindMe found at " & c.Address
                End If
            Next c

            'IN CASE SOURCE HEADER IS COLUMN B
            If c.Address = "$B$1" Then
                'Copy Column B to Column C
                Range("B1:B9999").Copy Range("C1:C9999")

                'Overwrite English for Translation on cell C1
                Range("C1").Value = "Translation"

                'Hide Columns
                Columns("A").Hidden = True
                Columns("B").Hidden = True
                .Close SaveChanges:=True

                'IN CASE SOURCE HEADER IS COLUMN C
            ElseIf c.Address = "$C$1" Then

                'Copy Column C to Column D
                Range("C1:C9999").Copy Range("D1:D9999")

                'Overwrite English for Translation on cell D1
                Range("D1").Value = "Translation"

                'Hide Columns A, B and C
                Columns("A").Hidden = True
                Columns("B").Hidden = True
                Columns("C").Hidden = True
                .Close SaveChanges:=True

                'IN CASE SOURCE HEADER IS COLUMN D
            ElseIf c.Address = "$D$1" Then

                'Copy Column D to Column E
                Range("D1:D9999").Copy Range("E1:E9999")

                'Overwrite English for Translation on cell E1
                Range("E1").Value = "Translation"

                'Hide Columns A B C D
                Columns("A").Hidden = True
                Columns("B").Hidden = True
                Columns("C").Hidden = True
                Columns("D").Hidden = True
                .Close SaveChanges:=True

                'IN CASE SOURCE HEADER IS COLUMN E
            ElseIf c.Address = "$E$1" Then

                'Copy Column E to Column F
                Range("E1:E9999").Copy Range("F1:F9999")

                'Overwrite English for Translation on cell F1
                Range("F1").Value = "Translation"

                'Hide Columns A, B and C
                Columns("A").Hidden = True
                Columns("B").Hidden = True
                Columns("C").Hidden = True
                Columns("D").Hidden = True
                Columns("E").Hidden = True
                .Close SaveChanges:=True

                'IN CASE SOURCE HEADER IS COLUMN F
            ElseIf c.Address = "$F$1" Then

                'Copy Column F to Column G
                Range("F1:F9999").Copy Range("G1:G9999")

                'Overwrite English for Translation on cell G1
                Range("G1").Value = "Translation"

                'Hide Columns A B C D E F
                Columns("A").Hidden = True
                Columns("B").Hidden = True
                Columns("C").Hidden = True
                Columns("D").Hidden = True
                Columns("E").Hidden = True
                Columns("F").Hidden = True

                .Close SaveChanges:=True

            End If

        End With

        strExtension = Dir

    Wend

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: In the first `For Each` loop, add `Exit For` inside the `If` statement when you find the English string in a cell. What happens if you don't find "English" in the file though?

Comment: You `c` is only active in the first `FOR` loop. Once you find the column, assign the address to a variable and then reference that variable for the column you want to work with

Comment: If the titles you want are static, you can do something like `set foundcell = ws.row(1).find(lookupval(i))` // `if foundcell <> nothing then`, and loop through each of the header names (assumes they're found in Row 1).  might be a touch slower than a loop or `match`, but would get the job done.

Comment: Are you ever needing to find the location of your ID?  Shouldn't have assumed, as that is part of my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub multimacro_test()


Dim wbOpen As Workbook
Dim MyDir As Variant

Dim c As Range
Dim location As String

MyDir = InputBox("Paste here the folder where you excel files are located.")
strExtension = Dir(MyDir & "\*.xlsx")

While strExtension <> vbNullString
Set wbOpen = Workbooks.Open(MyDir & "\" & strExtension)

With wbOpen


Dim foundcell As Range
Set foundcell = wbOpen.Sheets(1).Rows(1).Find("English")
If Not foundcell Is Nothing Then
    Dim col As Long
    col = foundcell.Column
End If

Range(Cells(1, col), Cells(9999, col)).Copy Range(Cells(1, col + 1), Cells(9999, col + 1))

If col <> 1 Then Range(Columns(1), Columns(col)).Hidden = True
Range(Cells(1, col + 1), Cells(1, col + 1)).Value = "Translation"
Rows(1).Hidden = True


.Close Savechanges:=True

End With

strExtension = Dir

Wend

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing comment as an answer due to reading code in a comment is near abysmal.

---

Try using `find()` for your header name(s):

```
dim foundcell as range
set foundcell = wbOpen.Sheets(1).Rows(1).Find("English")
if foundcell <> nothing then
    dim col as long
    col = foundcell.column
    `run your code for what to do when you have found English
end if
```

The above accounts for a single lookup value.  You can loop through values if you might have "ID" in another location, as well, such that:

```
dim lookupval as variant
lookupval = array("ID","English")
dim i as long
for i = lbound(lookupval) to ubound(lookupval)
    dim foundcell as range
    set foundcell = wbOpen.Sheets(1).Rows(1).Find(lookupval(i))
    if foundcell <> nothing then
        dim col as long
        col = foundcell.column
        `run your code for what to do when you have found English
    end if
next i
```

---

A couple benefits to this approach:

```
range(cells(1,col),cells(9999,col)).copy range(cells(1,col+1),cells(9999,col+1))
```

Above you see that you find the cell and use `col` and don't need to plan for a location, as the code is more dynamic.

```
if col <> 1 then Range(Columns(1),Columns(col-1)).Hidden = True
```

The above will work for all columns to be hidden PRIOR to the foundcell, since column 1 wouldn't need to be hidden if `col=1`.  No more having to manually set each column,. individually, to hidden.

Comment: That is amazing, this approach works! Thank you very much!

Comment: The only thing I am missing now is to add the String "Translation" to the header of the column after the column where English is found.